# Java Wrapper using rJava in R

Tags: java, r, rjava

I use [rJava](https://www.rforge.net/rJava/) package to create a wrapper for [java implementation](https://github.com/abahgat/suffixtree) in R. Currently, I want to create a wrapper for only two methods (put and search) of **GeneralizedSuffixTree** class present in the mentioned java implementation.

The signature of `search()` method of `GeneralizedSuffixTree` class is

```
public Collection<Integer> search(String word){
        return search(word, -1);
    }
```

Correspondingly, I have created a following wrapper method:

```
   callsearch <- function(key){
     hook2 <- .jnew("GeneralizedSuffixTree") # instance of class
     out <- .jcall(hook2,"Ljava/lang/Object","search",as.character(key), evalArray= FALSE, evalString = FALSE)
     return(out)
}
```

So, whenever I call the search method from rstudio with `callsearch("abcdea")`, I used to get following error

```
Error in .jcall(hook2, "Ljava/lang/Object", "search", as.character(key),  : 
  method search with signature (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object not found
```

I think I am doing some wrong casting for Integer collection in R. May I know where I am doing wrong?

Complete under-development wrapper package is present at the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u28knfftqaxncyj/AABrrQnpWwbkvKMZ3Tyo4Q0Ca?dl=0)

Comment: Does it work if you change returning type from `Collection<Integer>` into `Object` in your java code?

Comment: Yes, it works then. In my java code I changed Collections<Integer> to array return type, it worked perfectly. But I am more concerned  about collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the JNI type. Since search method returns a collection, and for the collection JNI specifies as `Ljava/util/Collection;`

Therefore the correct wrapper method is:

```
callsearch <- function(key){
     hook2 <- .jnew("GeneralizedSuffixTree") # instance of class
     out <- .jcall(hook2,"Ljava/util/Collection;","search",as.character(key), evalArray= FALSE, evalString = FALSE)
     return(out)
}
```

**Additional Info:** For any java class, the JNI type can be found at command prompt

```
 javap -s <java-classname>
```

Example for collections: `javap -s java.util.Collections`